# Get error when i try to test Multi-Room Chat Application sample code

Tags: node.js

i found [this sample code from github](https://github.com/uditalias/chat-nodejs) as `chat-nodejs` named and i want to test it how is it work, after installing `socket.io` and `expressjs` and running server and click to connect to server i get this error on `firebug`:

```
GET https://apis.google.com/_/scs/apps-static/_/js/k=...TcCOZ5yY8jtGvNKVwrKHFFcvb9eCe_w/cb=gapi.loaded_1

GET http://localhost/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LbtPp7S


"NetworkError:404 Not Found - 
       http://localhost/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LbtPp7S"?EIO=3&...LbtPp7S

Cross-Origin Request Blocked: 
The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at 
http://localhost/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LbtPp7S. 
(Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).
```

Answer (score 0):

You're getting a `NetworkError:404 Not Found` because the `serverAddress` in Line 15 of [chat.io.js](https://github.com/uditalias/chat-nodejs/blob/master/public/scripts/chat.io.js#L15) doesn't have the server port `8080` in it. Add port number to it.

```
serverAddress = 'http://localhost:8080',
```

Additionally, `socket.io` might not work well if the client and server installation of it, are of different version. 
`index.html` doesn't use a local one. The recent version of `socket.io` dint work for this repo. I had to install `0.9.13` on the server side for it to work.